# CSS :: Difference between .className and div.className

Tags: html, css

I write a html element as below ::

```
<div class="box"> Foo box </div>
```

and write css like

```
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

or

div.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to ask that how the both css for box class is different than each other.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference is that in the first class you tell that all element (`div`, `p`, `span` ...) with class `box` have that attribute.
Like this:

```
<span class="box">test</span>
<div class="box">test</div>
<p class="box">test</p>
```

The second class means that only div with class `box` has that attribute

Only this elements get second class:

```
<div class="box">test</div>
```

The `selector` before the class specify which type of elements can take this class

Answer (score 7):

One very important difference between `div.box` and simply `.box` is in something called **[selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)**. It is a set of rules which defines which selector gets more weight once the browser starts going through all the selectors that potentially have influence on a particular element.

What this means is easily demonstrated in the following example ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BN8Zk/))

We have a simple div containing some text.

```
<div class="box">
    Zarro boogs found!
</div>
```

Now we add some CSS selectors to the example.

```
div.box {
    padding:0.8em;
    background: #bd0000;
    color: #fff;
}
.box {
    color: #bd0000;
}
```

One of the most basic rules of CSS is that selectors can be redefined in a way that whatever definition comes last and has influence on a particular element its the one that is going to be used (the sole exception being when using `!important` which always takes precedence).

Now in the above example redefining the .`box` class selector should actually hide the text but instead its still visible. How is that possible if we said that latter rules always take precedence? Its because the `div.box` rule has a higher specificity that `.box` since it actually gets points for containing both an element (`div`) and a class selector (`.box`) in its selector declaration (`div.box`).

Of course the `div.box` rule will be applied only on a `div` element but since class selectors are often reusable pieces of code there is plenty of situations when they are used on divs.

Although the rules in the official W3 specification are not that hard to understand they are sometimes pretty hard to remember. That's why I would like to recommend an excellent article on CSS selector specificity which can be found [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

In my opinion selector specificity is by far the most important thing to master when it comes to tracing inheritance problems with CSS stylesheets.

Comment: This is very useful doc for me and also provided links are nice.

Answer (score 6):

`.box` means any element having class box.

Example:

```
<div class="box">...</div>
<section class="box">...</section>
<span class="box">...</span>
```

`div.box` means only div element having class box.

Example:

```
<div class="box">...</div>
```